# Create xml type with no body

Tags: xml, xsd

Hopefully this is an easy question.  How can I define an XML type such that the type doesn't have a body.

As an example I can define the Foo type as follows...

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

But that would allow the following...

```
<Foo id="7">STUFF I DON'T WANT</Foo>
```

Is there a way I can change the xsd so that the Foo element isn't allowed any body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you wanted:

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<xsd:element name="foo">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```